# HBase shell shows error when listing tables

Tags: hadoop, hbase

hbase(main):001:0> list
...
ava:75)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:147)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:163)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:292)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:135)
        at usr.local.hbase.bin.$_dot_dot_.bin.hirb.block_2$RUBY$start(/usr/local/hbase/bin/../bin/hirb.rb:183)
        at usr$local$hbase$bin$$_dot_dot_$bin$hirb$block_2$RUBY$start.call(usr$local$hbase$bin$$_dot_dot_$bin$hirb$block_2$RUBY$start:65535)
        at org.jruby.runtime.CompiledBlock.yield(CompiledBlock.java:112)
        at org.jruby.runtime.CompiledBlock.yield(CompiledBlock.java:95)
        at org.jruby.runtime.Block.yield(Block.java:130)
        at org.jruby.RubyContinuation.enter(RubyContinuation.java:106)
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.rbCatch(RubyKernel.java:1192)
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel$s$1$0$rbCatch.call(RubyKernel$s$1$0$rbCatch.gen:65535)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:322)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:178)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:187)
        at usr.local.hbase.bin.$_dot_dot_.bin.hirb.method__5$RUBY$start(/usr/local/hbase/bin/../bin/hirb.rb:182)
        at usr$local$hbase$bin$$_dot_dot_$bin$hirb$method__5$RUBY$start.call(usr$local$hbase$bin$$_dot_dot_$bin$hirb$method__5$RUBY$start:65535)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:203)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.CompiledMethod.call(CompiledMethod.java:255)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:292)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:135)
        at usr.local.hbase.bin.$_dot_dot_.bin.hirb.**file**(/usr/local/hbase/bin/../bin/hirb.rb:188)
        at usr.local.hbase.bin.$_dot_dot_.bin.hirb.load(/usr/local/hbase/bin/../bin/hirb.rb)
        at org.jruby.Ruby.runScript(Ruby.java:693)
        at org.jruby.Ruby.runScript(Ruby.java:686)
        at org.jruby.Ruby.runNormally(Ruby.java:593)
        at org.jruby.Ruby.runFromMain(Ruby.java:442)
        at org.jruby.Main.doRunFromMain(Main.java:321)
        at org.jruby.Main.internalRun(Main.java:241)
        at org.jruby.Main.run(Main.java:207)
        at org.jruby.Main.run(Main.java:191)
        at org.jruby.Main.main(Main.java:171)

ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: Retried 7 times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: Retried 7 times**

It clearly shows that your HMaster is not running. Make sure you have configured HBase properly with all the necessary properties. Are you able to see anything at **HBase's WebUI(hmaster:60010)**? See the HMaster logs for more help. You can find logs inside **${HBASE_HOME}/logs** if not changed.

Answer (score 1):

I recently got this same error.
Steps to resolve this (In my case this worked),

1. start hbase if not started using `./start-hbase.sh`
2. Again, try to start hbase using `./start-hbase.sh` and this time it would say "`Master is already ruuning at XXXX process id`"
3. Copy the process id of master using `ps -a` command from terminal, kill the process.
4. stop hbase using command `./stop-hbase.sh`
5. Now again start hbase and check the connection using "status" command from hbase shell.