# hbase shell jruby error

Tags: shell, hadoop, hbase

I am using HBase Version: `0.94.27`. After running `hbase shell`, when I write `list` or try to create a table, I am getting jruby error(error log is below.). I checked jps and `26100 HMaster` is working but I cannot do anything in hbase shell.
I have checked some links but they did not solve the error.
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831457/hbase-shell-shows-error-when-listing-tables) [Link](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hbase-user/201307.mbox/%3CCALte62y1MiSKmGxkgTRANN04GagCJfjqmpG5ru1o3GjCAOfOcA@mail.gmail.com%3E) [Link](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/5150/hbase-shell-error-javalangunsatisfiedlinkerror.html) [Link](http://qnalist.com/questions/4471310/hbase-shell-showing-error-when-giving-commands)

I was using version `1.1.3` before `0.94.27` and it was working perfectly. I have to use version `0.94.27` to be able to work with Play Framework.

```
hbase(main):001:0> list
TABLE
    at org.jruby.ast.FCallNoArgBlockNode.interpret(FCallNoArgBlockNode.java:32)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(ASTInterpreter.java:112)
    at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.evalBlockBody(InterpretedBlock.java:374)
    at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yield(InterpretedBlock.java:347)
    at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yield(InterpretedBlock.java:304)
    at org.jruby.runtime.Block.yield(Block.java:130)
    at org.jruby.RubyContinuation.enter(RubyContinuation.java:106)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.rbCatch(RubyKernel.java:1192)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel$s$1$0$rbCatch.call(RubyKernel$s$1$0$rbCatch.gen:65535)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:322)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:178)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:187)
    at org.jruby.ast.FCallOneArgBlockNode.interpret(FCallOneArgBlockNode.java:34)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:75)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:169)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:171)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:302)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:144)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:153)
    at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgBlockNode.interpret(CallNoArgBlockNode.java:64)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:75)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:147)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:163)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:292)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:135)
    at home.alican.hbase_minus_0_dot_94_dot_27.bin.hirb.block_2$RUBY$start(/home/alican/hbase-0.94.27/bin/hirb.rb:183)
    at home$alican$hbase_minus_0_dot_94_dot_27$bin$hirb$block_2$RUBY$start.call(home$alican$hbase_minus_0_dot_94_dot_27$bin$hirb$block_2$RUBY$start:65535)
    at org.jruby.runtime.CompiledBlock.yield(CompiledBlock.java:112)
    at org.jruby.runtime.CompiledBlock.yield(CompiledBlock.java:95)
    at org.jruby.runtime.Block.yield(Block.java:130)
    at org.jruby.RubyContinuation.enter(RubyContinuation.java:106)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.rbCatch(RubyKernel.java:1192)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel$s$1$0$rbCatch.call(RubyKernel$s$1$0$rbCatch.gen:65535)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:322)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:178)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:187)
    at home.alican.hbase_minus_0_dot_94_dot_27.bin.hirb.method__5$RUBY$start(/home/alican/hbase-0.94.27/bin/hirb.rb:182)
    at home$alican$hbase_minus_0_dot_94_dot_27$bin$hirb$method__5$RUBY$start.call(home$alican$hbase_minus_0_dot_94_dot_27$bin$hirb$method__5$RUBY$start:65535)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:203)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.CompiledMethod.call(CompiledMethod.java:255)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:292)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:135)
    at home.alican.hbase_minus_0_dot_94_dot_27.bin.hirb.__file__(/home/alican/hbase-0.94.27/bin/hirb.rb:188)
    at home.alican.hbase_minus_0_dot_94_dot_27.bin.hirb.load(/home/alican/hbase-0.94.27/bin/hirb.rb)
    at org.jruby.Ruby.runScript(Ruby.java:693)
    at org.jruby.Ruby.runScript(Ruby.java:686)
    at org.jruby.Ruby.runNormally(Ruby.java:593)
    at org.jruby.Ruby.runFromMain(Ruby.java:442)
    at org.jruby.Main.doRunFromMain(Main.java:321)
    at org.jruby.Main.internalRun(Main.java:241)
    at org.jruby.Main.run(Main.java:207)
    at org.jruby.Main.run(Main.java:191)
    at org.jruby.Main.main(Main.java:171)
16/03/01 17:23:24 ERROR zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher: hconnection0x0 Received unexpected KeeperException, re-throwing exception
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/master
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.exists(ZooKeeper.java:1041)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.exists(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.watchAndCheckExists(ZKUtil.java:420)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperNodeTracker.start(ZooKeeperNodeTracker.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.ensureZookeeperTrackers(HConnectionManager.java:723)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getMaster(HConnectionManager.java:786)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.<init>(HBaseAdmin.java:129)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaConstructor.newInstanceDirect(JavaConstructor.java:275)
    at org.jruby.java.invokers.ConstructorInvoker.call(ConstructorInvoker.java:91)
    at org.jruby.java.invokers.ConstructorInvoker.call(ConstructorInvoker.java:178)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:322)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:178)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:182)
    at org.jruby.java.proxies.ConcreteJavaProxy$2.call(ConcreteJavaProxy.java:47)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:322)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:178)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:182)
    at org.jruby.RubyClass.newInstance(RubyClass.java:813)
    at org.jruby.RubyClass$i$newInstance.call(RubyClass$i$newInstance.gen:65535)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodZeroOrOneOrNBlock.call(JavaMethod.java:266)
    at org.jruby.java.proxies.ConcreteJavaProxy$3.call(ConcreteJavaProxy.java:143)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:312)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:169)
    at org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)
    at org.jruby.ast.InstAsgnNode.interpret(InstAsgnNode.java:95)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:75)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:255)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:203)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:342)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:212)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:216)
    at org.jruby.RubyClass.newInstance(RubyClass.java:820)
    at org.jruby.RubyClass$i$newInstance.call(RubyClass$i$newInstance.gen:65535)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodZeroOrOneOrTwoOrNBlock.call(JavaMethod.java:283)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:332)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:203)
    at org.jruby.ast.CallTwoArgNode.interpret(CallTwoArgNode.java:59)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:75)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:190)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:179)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:312)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:169)
    at org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)
    at org.jruby.ast.InstAsgnNode.interpret(InstAsgnNode.java:95)
    at org.jruby.ast.OpAsgnOrNode.interpret(OpAsgnOrNode.java:100)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:75)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:147)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:163)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:292)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:135)
    at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:63)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:75)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:147)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:163)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:292)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:135)
    at org.jruby.ast.VCallNode.interpret(VCallNode.java:86)
    at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:63)
    at org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)
    at org.jruby.ast.LocalAsgnNode.interpret(LocalAsgnNode.java:123)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:75)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:147)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:163)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:292)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:135)
    at org.jruby.ast.FCallSpecialArgNode.interpret(FCallSpecialArgNode.java:37)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(ASTInterpreter.java:112)
    at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.evalBlockBody(InterpretedBlock.java:374)
    at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yield(InterpretedBlock.java:295)
    at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yieldSpecific(InterpretedBlock.java:229)
    at org.jruby.runtime.Block.yieldSpecific(Block.java:99)
    at org.jruby.ast.ZYieldNode.interpret(ZYieldNode.java:25)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.executeBody(RescueNode.java:216)
    at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpretWithJavaExceptions(RescueNode.java:120)
    at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpret(RescueNode.java:110)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:75)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:169)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:171)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:302)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:144)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:153)
    at org.jruby.ast.FCallSpecialArgBlockNode.interpret(FCallSpecialArgBlockNode.java:34)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.executeBody(RescueNode.java:216)
    at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpretWithJavaExceptions(RescueNode.java:120)
    at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpret(RescueNode.java:110)
    at org.jruby.ast.EnsureNode.interpret(EnsureNode.java:96)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:75)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:190)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:179)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:312)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:169)
    at org.jruby.ast.CallSpecialArgNode.interpret(CallSpecialArgNode.java:67)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:75)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:190)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:179)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:312)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:169)
    at org.jruby.ast.CallSpecialArgNode.interpret(CallSpecialArgNode.java:67)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:75)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:147)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:163)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:292)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:135)
    at org.jruby.ast.VCallNode.interpret(VCallNode.java:86)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.ast.RootNode.interpret(RootNode.java:129)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_EVAL(ASTInterpreter.java:96)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.evalWithBinding(ASTInterpreter.java:161)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.evalCommon(RubyKernel.java:1135)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.eval(RubyKernel.java:1088)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel$s$0$3$eval.call(RubyKernel$s$0$3$eval.gen:65535)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:181)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:282)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:71)
    at org.jruby.ast.FCallManyArgsNode.interpret(FCallManyArgsNode.java:60)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:75)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:120)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:134)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:154)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:282)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:71)
    at org.jruby.ast.CallManyArgsNode.interpret(CallManyArgsNode.java:59)
    at org.jruby.ast.FCallOneArgNode.interpret(FCallOneArgNode.java:36)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:75)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:233)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:195)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:332)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:203)
    at org.jruby.ast.CallTwoArgNode.interpret(CallTwoArgNode.java:59)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.executeBody(RescueNode.java:216)
    at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpretWithJavaExceptions(RescueNode.java:120)
    at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpret(RescueNode.java:110)
    at org.jruby.ast.BeginNode.interpret(BeginNode.java:83)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(ASTInterpreter.java:112)
    at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.evalBlockBody(InterpretedBlock.java:374)
    at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yield(InterpretedBlock.java:295)
    at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yieldSpecific(InterpretedBlock.java:229)
    at org.jruby.runtime.Block.yieldSpecific(Block.java:99)
    at org.jruby.ast.ZYieldNode.interpret(ZYieldNode.java:25)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.ast.EnsureNode.interpret(EnsureNode.java:96)
    at org.jruby.ast.BeginNode.interpret(BeginNode.java:83)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:75)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:212)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:187)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:322)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:178)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:187)
    at org.jruby.ast.FCallOneArgBlockNode.interpret(FCallOneArgBlockNode.java:34)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(ASTInterpreter.java:112)
    at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.evalBlockBody(InterpretedBlock.java:374)
    at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yieldSpecific(InterpretedBlock.java:260)
    at org.jruby.runtime.Block.yieldSpecific(Block.java:117)
    at org.jruby.ast.YieldTwoNode.interpret(YieldTwoNode.java:31)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:117)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.executeBody(RescueNode.java:216)
    at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpretWithJavaExceptions(RescueNode.java:120)
    at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpret(RescueNode.java:110)
    at org.jruby.ast.BeginNode.interpret(BeginNode.java:83)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(ASTInterpreter.java:112)
    at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.evalBlockBody(InterpretedBlock.java:374)
    at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yield(InterpretedBlock.java:295)
    at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yieldSpecific(InterpretedBlock.java:229)
    at org.jruby.runtime.Block.yieldSpecific(Block.java:99)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.loop(RubyKernel.java:1420)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel$s$0$0$loop.call(RubyKernel$s$0$0$loop.gen:65535)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:302)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:144)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:153)
    at org.jruby.ast.FCallNoArgBlockNode.interpret(FCallNoArgBlockNode.java:32)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(ASTInterpreter.java:112)
    at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.evalBlockBody(InterpretedBlock.java:374)
    at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yield(InterpretedBlock.java:347)
    at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yield(InterpretedBlock.java:304)
    at org.jruby.runtime.Block.yield(Block.java:130)
    at org.jruby.RubyContinuation.enter(RubyContinuation.java:106)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.rbCatch(RubyKernel.java:1192)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel$s$1$0$rbCatch.call(RubyKernel$s$1$0$rbCatch.gen:65535)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:322)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:178)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:187)
    at org.jruby.ast.FCallOneArgBlockNode.interpret(FCallOneArgBlockNode.java:34)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:75)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:169)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:171)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:302)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:144)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:153)
    at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgBlockNode.interpret(CallNoArgBlockNode.java:64)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:75)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:147)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:163)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:292)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:135)
    at home.alican.hbase_minus_0_dot_94_dot_27.bin.hirb.block_2$RUBY$start(/home/alican/hbase-0.94.27/bin/hirb.rb:183)
    at home$alican$hbase_minus_0_dot_94_dot_27$bin$hirb$block_2$RUBY$start.call(home$alican$hbase_minus_0_dot_94_dot_27$bin$hirb$block_2$RUBY$start:65535)
    at org.jruby.runtime.CompiledBlock.yield(CompiledBlock.java:112)
    at org.jruby.runtime.CompiledBlock.yield(CompiledBlock.java:95)
    at org.jruby.runtime.Block.yield(Block.java:130)
    at org.jruby.RubyContinuation.enter(RubyContinuation.java:106)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.rbCatch(RubyKernel.java:1192)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel$s$1$0$rbCatch.call(RubyKernel$s$1$0$rbCatch.gen:65535)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:322)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:178)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:187)
    at home.alican.hbase_minus_0_dot_94_dot_27.bin.hirb.method__5$RUBY$start(/home/alican/hbase-0.94.27/bin/hirb.rb:182)
    at home$alican$hbase_minus_0_dot_94_dot_27$bin$hirb$method__5$RUBY$start.call(home$alican$hbase_minus_0_dot_94_dot_27$bin$hirb$method__5$RUBY$start:65535)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:203)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.CompiledMethod.call(CompiledMethod.java:255)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:292)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:135)
    at home.alican.hbase_minus_0_dot_94_dot_27.bin.hirb.__file__(/home/alican/hbase-0.94.27/bin/hirb.rb:188)
    at home.alican.hbase_minus_0_dot_94_dot_27.bin.hirb.load(/home/alican/hbase-0.94.27/bin/hirb.rb)
    at org.jruby.Ruby.runScript(Ruby.java:693)
    at org.jruby.Ruby.runScript(Ruby.java:686)
    at org.jruby.Ruby.runNormally(Ruby.java:593)
    at org.jruby.Ruby.runFromMain(Ruby.java:442)
    at org.jruby.Main.doRunFromMain(Main.java:321)
    at org.jruby.Main.internalRun(Main.java:241)
    at org.jruby.Main.run(Main.java:207)
    at org.jruby.Main.run(Main.java:191)
    at org.jruby.Main.main(Main.java:171)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

We have to add JAVA_PATH inside hbase-env.sh which is in conf folder.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
```

Comment: + ran regionserver, master and zookeeper manually. example:  /bin/hbase-daemon.sh start regionserver